# STM32F411E-DISCO BLDC Hall sensor

Tags: stm32, sensor, brushless-dc-motor, hall-effect

With an STM32F411E-DISCO, I am trying to obtain the RPM value by receiving data from the Hall sensor of a BLDC motor. For this, I activated XOR On / Hall effect mode and connected the pins of the Hall sensors to the relevant places.

```
HAL_TIMEx_HallSensor_Start(&htim2);

hall_out = pwm1 = (int32_t)htim2.Instance->CCR1
```

However, the data varies too much. I can't get a constant or meaningful output; it can be 4000 at one moment and 2 at another.

There is also a digital output pin on the ESC that can output data from the Hall sensors, but I have not been able to read data from it.

Can you help me with this? I've scoured the internet almost completely but I can't find an example or anything that can help and I'm a rookie in this subject.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with your system, but why are you using pwm post-op the whole sensor probably should be read as a digital input high or low. So also should the output from the ESC.